# Why is using __slots__ in my class not making a difference in size?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently explained a friend the usage of `__slots__`. I wanted to demonstrate the result to him and used the following code:

```
import sys


class Foo:
    __slots__ = 'a', 'b'

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


a = Foo(10, 20)
b = Bar(10, 20)

print(sys.getsizeof(a))
print(sys.getsizeof(b))
```

The output on the console for Python 3 was:

```
 56
 56
```

The output for Python 2 was:

```
 72
 72
```

Why is there no difference in size?

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301295/measure-object-size-accurately-in-python-sys-getsizeof-not-functioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python2, you'll need to inherit from `object` to activate the `__slots__` machinery

The problem is that you are comparing apples with oranges.

`sys.getsizeof` is only a shallow size, ie. it's doesn't calculate the size of all the interior objects.

for the `__slots__` version, you will see it is proportional to the number of slots

for the normal object, you should look at the size of the instance `__dict__` to make a reasonable comparison.

Another approach is to allocate a few million of these objects and see how much memory the operating system reports as used.

Answer (score 1):

John La Rooy's observation is correct that `sys.getsizeof` is shallow and therefore doesn't give the correct result. Using `pympler`'s `asizeof` module you can see there is a different answer:

```
from pympler import asizeof

class Foo:
    __slots__ = 'a', 'b'

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


x = Foo(10, 20)
y = Bar(10, 20)

print(asizeof.asizeof(x))
print(asizeof.asizeof(y))
```

Running:

```
python3 test.py
```

gives:

```
192
328
```