# How to find number of bytes in a variable?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

In C if I do

```
USHORT x;
ULONG y;
ULONGLONG yy;

printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(x), sizeof(y), sizeof(yy))
```

Output: 2 4 8

How can I get this in Python if I were to to

```
valByte = 0x16
valWord = 0x1234
valDWord = 0x12345678
val64Word = 0x1234567887654321
```

Output I expect should be 1, 2, 4, 8

thanks

Comment: Python doesn't really work like that - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Python integers do not *have* a size. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure they do, it just varies. You can use [`sys.getsizeof`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), though the value it gives should probably not be _used_ for anything.

Comment: @kwatford: have you actually tried to use that function on integers?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, it returns different values depending on the number of bytes needed to store the integer.

Comment: @kwatford: It returns the number of bytes python currently needs for the instance, yes, which happens to have a (small amount) of a correlation to how large the python integer is. But I doubt it is any use to the OP.

Comment: Like I said, probably shouldn't be used for anything. If he just wants it for informational purposes ("I wonder how much memory this datastructure takes up") it can be used. Not so much for most of the things you'd use the size for in C. OP has not yet said what he actually needs, though.

Comment: For informational purposes, I made a plot of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30008338/2087463, it was interesting to see...

Answer (score 5):

In Python3 there is the bit_length method:

```
>>> import math

>>> math.ceil(0x16.bit_length()/8)
1
>>> math.ceil(0x1234.bit_length()/8)
2
>>> math.ceil(0x12345678.bit_length()/8)
4
>>> math.ceil(0x1234567887654321.bit_length()/8)
8
```

In Python2.7, `long` integers also have the `bit_length` method:

```
>>> (10**20).bit_length()
67

>>> x = 123
>>> long(x).bit_length()
7
```

Comment: This is fantastic and answers my question. I am from the C world and am porting a C program to Python. These values I mention represent register width and they come in all sizes. I need to know the size of the register, thank you very much unutbu

Comment: However one issue please ...  I have to use the variable name, i cannot use the actual number right? In my case the variable name is always reg. reg can hold any one of the values, byte, word ... Just for an example I gave different names. reg.bit_length does not work. So how do I do do the same work with a variable name?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: `reg.bit_length()` will work.  Are you sure you need to worry about this in Python?  I suspect you are doing too-literal a translation from C to Python, and there is an easier way to accomplish your goal.  What will you do with these "integer sizes"?

Comment: In C this is the program:

Comment: Sorry ignore the above comment. My idea is to check if each bit is set from Right to left (LSB to MSB) and if the bit set then to print out the meaning of that bit. Like the error registers or status registers. for i in range(reg):
    shift = reg & (1 << i) the problem here is val will be the actual value of the number where as I want it to be number of bits

Comment: BTW I did try reg.bit_length() and it gave me an error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'bit_length'

Comment: for now I have hard coded the highest bit value possible (64) and it works but I wish to remove the hard coding                     regVal = 0x16
for i in range(64):
    bitVal = regVal & (1 << i)
    if (bitVal):
        print '1' #"The meaning of that bit being set to 1" 
    else:
        print '0' #"The meaning of that bit being set to 0" 
print Done

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: (1): `reg.bit_length()` only works in Python3, not in Python2. The `AttributeError` you received strongly suggests you are using Python2. However, in Python2, `long` integers do have the `bit_length` method, so you could do `long(reg).bit_length()`. (2): Python `long` integers are unbounded. They can certainly be larger than 64 bits. For example, `(10**20).bit_length()` is 67. (3): Your code suggests you want the binary string representation for `regVal`. That could be done with `'{0:b}'.format(regVal)`. (4): Pay attention to Ned Batchelder's comment. He is invariably right. :)

Comment: Correction: In Python2.7, `long`s have the `bit_length` method. In earlier versions of Python, use the `bit_length` function shown in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#long.bit_length).

Comment: YES!! The docs helped me, I am done. Sorry I am stuck with 2.6, do not have the freedom to go to higher versions of Python. Thanks to all this case can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.getsizeof`, but the result may be annoying because there is a minimum that a integer can be.

For example, in my 64 bits PC all you variables have a size of 24 bytes.