# How to get the memory usage of Python object without importing any third party libraries like hpy or PySizer?

Tags: python, memory, stack, overflow, monitor

I'm writing Python test cases for testing a COM written in C++. Currently I re-write a recursion function of the COM to non-recursion in order to avoid the call stack overflow. Then I need to write a Python test case to cover this change, but I don't know how to monitor the call stack information in Python, maybe I should monitor the memory usage of the object.

I googled to find that almost every advise is to use PySizer or heap, but my question is I can't import any third party libraries at will, since the test case will be run in other colleagues' computer, I can't push them all to install the third party libraries. So who can help me? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)