# Read string up to a certain size in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string stored in a variable. Is there a way to read a string up to a certain size e.g. File objects have f.read(size) which can read up to a certain size?

Comment: Slice notation won't overrun a string: `s = 'f' * 5; t = s[:50]`

Comment: Yes I want something like substring but using the given size in bytes

Comment: Are you sure you want bytes and not characters? (Don't forget unicode)

Comment: I want characters. Note the size is in bytes

Comment: Basically I want send a string over a socket so I need to split my string in chunks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python) post for finding object sizes in python.

If you are wanting to read the string from the start until a certain size MAX is reached, then return that new (possibly shorter string) you might want to try something like this:

```
import sys

MAX = 176 #bytes
totalSize = 0
newString = ""

s = "MyStringLength"

for c in s:
    totalSize = totalSize + sys.getsizeof(c)
    if totalSize <= MAX:
        newString = newString + str(c)
    elif totalSize > MAX:
        #string that is slightly larger or the same size as MAX
        print newString
        break
```

This prints 'MyString' which is less than (or equal to) 176 Bytes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just saw you want 'size' in characters and not bytes. John's post then seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
message = 'a long string which contains a lot of valuable information.'
bite = 10

while message:
    # bite off a chunk of the string
    chunk = message[:bite]

    # set message to be the remaining portion
    message = message[bite:]

    do_something_with(chunk)
```