# What resources does an instance of a class use?

Tags: python, class, memory-management, instance, cpython

How efficient is python (cpython I guess) when allocating resources for a newly created instance of a class? I have a situation where I will need to instantiate a node class millions of times to make a tree structure. Each of the node objects *should* be lightweight, just containing a few numbers and references to parent and child nodes.

For example, will python need to allocate memory for all the "double underscore" properties of each instantiated object (e.g. the docstrings, `__dict__`, `__repr__`, `__class__`, etc, etc), either to create these properties individually or store pointers to where they are defined by the class? Or is it efficient and does not need to store anything except the custom stuff I defined that needs to be stored in each object?

Comment: I don't have actual docs to back me up on this, but I *think* all that information (docstrings and method definitions) is stored *with the Class*, so that only variables and values are stored with the instance. So, the instance would contain enough allocated memory for all its variables and method pointers, but not the code inside those methods (that's static and would live with the Class).

Comment: Consider creating node class with `__slots__` attribute - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots

Comment: Related: [How does python store objects in memory](//stackoverflow.com/q/52692828)

Comment: docstrings are also not created per instance (unless you do something really weird), so there should be no need to care about them. But you can tell python to omit them anyway by running it with [the -OO flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-oo).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Superficially it's quite simple: Methods, class variables, and the class docstring are stored in the class (function docstrings are stored in the function). Instance variables are stored in the instance. The instance also references the class so you can look up the methods. Typically all of them are stored in dictionaries (the `__dict__`).

So yes, the short answer is: Python doesn't store methods in the instances, but all instances need to have a reference to the class.

For example if you have a simple class like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.a}, {self.b})"

instance_1 = MyClass()
instance_2 = MyClass()
```

Then in-memory it looks (very simplified) like this:

[image]

### Going deeper

However there are a few things that important when going deeper in CPython:

- Having a dictionary as abstraction leads to quite a bit of overhead: You need a reference to the instance dictionary (bytes) and each entry in the dictionary stores the hash (8bytes), a pointer to a key (8bytes) and a pointer to the stored attribute (another 8 bytes). Also dictionaries generally over-allocate so that adding another attribute doesn't trigger a dictionary-resize.
- Python doesn't have "value-types", even an integer will be an instance. That means that you don't need 4 bytes to store an integer - Python needs (on my computer) 24bytes to store the integer 0 and at least 28 bytes to store integers different from zero. However references to other objects just require 8 bytes (pointer).
- CPython uses reference counting so each instance needs a reference count (8bytes). Also most of CPythons classes participate in the cyclic garbage collector, which incurs an overhead of another 24bytes per instance. In addition to these classes that can be weak-referenced (most of them) also have a `__weakref__` field (another 8 bytes).

At this point it's also necessary to point out that CPython optimizes for a few of these "problems":

- Python uses [Key-Sharing Dictionaries](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/) to avoid some of the memory overheads (hash and key) of instance dictionaries.
- You can use `__slots__` in classes to avoid `__dict__` and `__weakref__`. This can give a significantly less memory-footprint per instance.
- Python interns some values, for example if you create a small integer it will not create a new integer instance but return a reference to an already existing instance.

Given all that and that several of these points (especially the points about optimizing) are implementation-details it's hard to give an canonical answer about the effective memory-requirements of Python classes.

### Reducing the memory footprint of instances

However in case you want to reduce the memory-footprint of your instances definitely give `__slots__` a try. They do have draw-backs but in case they don't apply to you they are a very good way to reduce the memory.

```py
class Slotted:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
```

If that's not enough and you operate with lots of "value types" you could also go a step further and create extension classes. These are classes that are defined in C but are wrapped so that you can use them in Python.

For convenience I'm using the IPython bindings for Cython here to simulate an extension class:

```py
%load_ext cython
```

```py
%%cython

cdef class Extensioned:
    cdef long long a
    cdef long long b

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
```

### Measuring the memory usage

The remaining interesting question after all this theory is: How can we measure the memory?

I also use a normal class:

```py
class Dicted:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
```

I'm generally using [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (even though it's a proxy method) for measuring memory impact and simply measure how much memory it used before and after. The measurements are a bit offset because I need to keep the instances in memory somehow, otherwise the memory would be reclaimed (immediately). Also this is only an approximation because Python actually does quite a bit of memory housekeeping especially when there are lots of create/deletes.

```py
import os
import psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

runs = 10
instances = 100_000

memory_dicted = [0] * runs
memory_slotted = [0] * runs
memory_extensioned = [0] * runs

for run_index in range(runs):
    for store, cls in [(memory_dicted, Dicted), (memory_slotted, Slotted), (memory_extensioned, Extensioned)]:
        before = process.memory_info().rss
        l = [cls() for _ in range(instances)]
        store[run_index] = process.memory_info().rss - before
        l.clear()  # reclaim memory for instances immediately
```

The memory will not be exactly identical for each run because Python re-uses some memory and sometimes also keeps memory around for other purposes but it should at least give a reasonable hint:

```
>>> min(memory_dicted) / 1024**2, min(memory_slotted) / 1024**2, min(memory_extensioned) / 1024**2
(15.625, 5.3359375, 2.7265625)
```

I used the `min` here mostly because I was interested what the minimum was and I divided by `1024**2` to convert the bytes to MegaBytes.

Summary: As expected the normal class with dict will need more memory than classes with slots but extension classes (if applicable and available) can have an even lower memory footprint.

Another tools that could be very handy for measuring memory usage is [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), although I haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @MSeifert, you make very good points; what would be your suggestion to measuring the memory requirements?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I typically use [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) (both proxies). But one only gets approximations with these tools because a lot of the memory-housekeeping is done by the Python interpreter which often interferes with the results from these tools. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer @MSeifert, it is in depth and well explained; I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 9):

*[edit] It is not easy to get an accurate measurement of memory usage by a python process; **I don't think my answer completely answers the question**, but it is one approach that may be useful in some cases.*

*Most approaches use proxy methods (create n objects and estimate the impact on the system memory), and external libraries attempting to wrap those methods. For instance, threads can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850995/tracking-maximum-memory-usage-by-a-python-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended) [/edit]*

On `cPython 3.7`, The minimum size of a regular class instance is 56 bytes; with `__slots__` (no dictionary), 16 bytes.

```
import sys

class A:
    pass

class B:
    __slots__ = ()
    pass

a = A()
b = B()
sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b)
```

#### output:

```
56, 16
```

Docstrings, class variables, & type annotations are not found at the instance level:

```
import sys

class A:
    """regular class"""
    a: int = 12

class B:
    """slotted class"""
    b: int = 12
    __slots__ = ()

a = A()
b = B()
sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b)
```

#### output:

```
56, 16
```

*[edit ]In addition, see [@LiuXiMin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56581237/what-resources-does-an-instance-of-a-class-use/56598070#56598070) for **a measure of the size of the class definition**. [/edit]*

Comment: I'm not clear on what `sys.getsizeof` is actually measuring. If I add variables to an object at the instance level (e.g. `a.__doc__='blah'`) `sys.getsizeof(a)` gives the same number.

Comment: There is a detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574076/what-is-the-difference-between-len-and-sys-getsizeof-methods-in-python

Comment: In that case I don't think getsizeof can totally answer my question. It seems like each instance could contain unique objects (each taking up memory) that wouldn't show up in getsizeof.

Comment: I agree @Alex, my answer is incomplete and not satisfactory; I added a note at the top to warn the reader.

Comment: I searched a little bit, and, as expected, answers are not straightforward and forthcoming; most approaches use proxy methods (create n objects and estimate the impact on the system memory), and external libraries attempting to wrap those methods. For instance, threads can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850995/tracking-maximum-memory-usage-by-a-python-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended)

Answer (score 7):

The most basic object in CPython is just a [type reference and reference count](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject). Both are word-sized (i.e. 8 byte on a 64 bit machine), so the minimal size of an instance is 2 words (i.e. 16 bytes on a 64 bit machine).

```
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> class Minimal:
...      __slots__ = ()  # do not allow dynamic fields
...
>>> minimal = Minimal()
>>> sys.getsizeof(minimal)
16
```

**Each instance needs space for `__class__` and a hidden reference count.**

---

The type reference (roughly `object.__class__`) means that *instances fetch content from their class*. Everything you define on the class, not the instance, does not take up space per instance.

```
>>> class EmptyInstance:
...      __slots__ = ()  # do not allow dynamic fields
...      foo = 'bar'
...      def hello(self):
...          return "Hello World"
...
>>> empty_instance = EmptyInstance()
>>> sys.getsizeof(empty_instance)  # instance size is unchanged
16
>>> empty_instance.foo             # instance has access to class attributes
'bar'
>>> empty_instance.hello()         # methods are class attributes!
'Hello World'
```

Note that methods too are *functions on the class*. Fetching one via an instance invokes the [function's data descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) to create a temporary method object by partially binding the instance to the function. As a result, *methods do not increase instance size*.

**Instances do not need space for class attributes, including `__doc__` and *any* methods.**

---

The only thing that increases the size of instances is content stored on the instance. There are three ways to achieve this: `__dict__`, `__slots__` and [container types](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject). All of these store content assigned to the instance in some way.

- By default, instances have a [`__dict__` field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) - a reference to a mapping that stores attributes. Such classes *also* have some other default fields, like `__weakref__`.

  ```
  >>> class Dict:
  ...     # class scope
  ...     def __init__(self):
  ...         # instance scope - access via self
  ...         self.bar = 2                   # assign to instance
  ...
  >>> dict_instance = Dict()
  >>> dict_instance.foo = 1                  # assign to instance
  >>> sys.getsizeof(dict_instance)           # larger due to more references
  56
  >>> sys.getsizeof(dict_instance.__dict__)  # __dict__ takes up space as well!
  240
  >>> dict_instance.__dict__                 # __dict__ stores attribute names and values
  {'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}
  ```

  **Each instance using `__dict__` uses space for the `dict`, the attribute names and values.**
- Adding a [`__slots__` field to the class](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) generates instances with a fixed data layout. This restricts the allowed attributes to those declared, but takes up little space on the instance. The `__dict__` and `__weakref__` slots are only created on request.

  ```
  >>> class Slots:
  ...     __slots__ = ('foo',)  # request accessors for instance data
  ...     def __init__(self):
  ...         # instance scope - access via self
  ...         self.foo = 2
  ...
  >>> slots_instance = Slots()
  >>> sys.getsizeof(slots_instance)           # 40 + 8 * fields
  48
  >>> slots_instance.bar = 1
  AttributeError: 'Slots' object has no attribute 'bar'
  >>> del slots_instance.foo
  >>> sys.getsizeof(slots_instance)           # size is fixed
  48
  >>> Slots.foo                               # attribute interface is descriptor on class
  <member 'foo' of 'Slots' objects>
  ```

  **Each instance using `__slots__` uses space only for the attribute values.**
- Inheriting from a container type, such as `list`, `dict` or `tuple`, allows to store items (`self[0]`) instead of attributes (`self.a`). This uses a compact internal storage *in addition* to either `__dict__` or `__slots__`. Such classes are rarely constructed manually - helpers such as `typing.NamedTuple` are often used.

  ```
  >>> from typing import NamedTuple
  >>>
  >>> class Named(NamedTuple):
  ...     foo: int
  ...
  >>> named_instance = Named(2)
  >>> sys.getsizeof(named_instance)
  56
  >>> named_instance.bar = 1
  AttributeError: 'Named' object has no attribute 'bar'
  >>> del named_instance.foo                  # behaviour inherited from container
  AttributeError: can't delete attribute
  >>> Named.foo                               # attribute interface is descriptor on class
  <property at 0x10bba3228>
  >>> Named.__len__                           # container interface/metadata such as length exists
  <slot wrapper '__len__' of 'tuple' objects>
  ```

  **Each instance of a derived container behaves like the base type, plus potential `__slots__` or `__dict__`.**

**The most lightweight instances use `__slots__` to only store attribute values.**

---

Note that a part of the `__dict__` overhead is commonly optimised by Python interpreters. CPython is capable of [sharing keys between instances](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/), which can [considerably reduce the size per instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419011/why-is-the-dict-of-instances-so-much-smaller-in-size-in-python-3). PyPy uses an optimises key-shared representation that [completely eliminates the difference](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/11/efficiently-implementing-python-objects.html) between `__dict__` and `__slots__`.

It is not possible to accurately measure the memory consumption of objects in all but the most trivial cases. Measuring the size of isolated objects misses related structures, such as `__dict__` using memory for *both* a pointer on the instance *and* an external `dict`. Measuring groups of objects miscounts shared objects (interned strings, small integers, ...) and lazy objects (e.g. the `dict` of `__dict__` only exists when accessed). Note that PyPy [does not implement `sys.getsizeof`](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html) [to avoid its misuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562838/is-there-any-alternative-to-sys-getsizeof-in-pypy).

In order to measure memory consumption, a full program measurement should be used. For example, one can use [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) or [`psutils` to get the own memory consumption while spawning objects](https://dev.nextthought.com/blog/2018/08/cpython-vs-pypy-memory-usage.html).

I have created one such [measurement script for *number of fields*, *number of instances* and *implementation variant*](https://gist.github.com/maxfischer2781/d6b617771e76ddd518f1de8b1221e57e). Values shown are *bytes/field* for an instance count of 1000000, on CPython 3.7.0 and PyPy3 3.6.1/7.1.1-beta0.

```
      # fields |     1 |     4 |     8 |    16 |    32 |    64 |
---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
python3: slots |  48.8 |  18.3 |  13.5 |  10.7 |   9.8 |   8.8 |
python3: dict  | 170.6 |  42.7 |  26.5 |  18.8 |  14.7 |  13.0 |
pypy3:   slots |  79.0 |  31.8 |  30.1 |  25.9 |  25.6 |  24.1 |
pypy3:   dict  |  79.2 |  31.9 |  29.9 |  27.2 |  24.9 |  25.0 |
```

For CPython, `__slots__` save about 30%-50% of memory versus `__dict__`. For PyPy, consumption is comparable. Interestingly, PyPy is worse than CPython with `__slots__`, and stays stable for extreme field counts.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to formulate this great answer @MisterMiyagi; I learned a lot from it. It was a difficult choice to decide who to award the bonus to, but a decision needed to be made.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it efficient and does not need to store anything except the custom stuff I defined that needs to be stored in each object?

Almost yes, except some certain space. Class in Python is already an instance of `type`, called metaclass. When new an instance of class object, the `custom stuff` are just those things in `__init__`. The attributes and methods defined in class won't 
spend more space.

As for the some certain space, just refer Reblochon Masque's answer, very good and impressive.

Maybe I can give one simple but illustrative example:

```
class T(object):
    def a(self):
        print(self)
t = T()
t.a()
# output: <__main__.T object at 0x1060712e8>
T.a(t)
# output: <__main__.T object at 0x1060712e8>
# as you see, t.a() equals T.a(t)

import sys
sys.getsizeof(T)
# output: 1056
sys.getsizeof(T())
# output: 56
```