# How much memory will a list with one million elements take up in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, reddit

There are more than a million subreddits on Reddit, according to [redditmetrics.com](http://redditmetrics.com/history).

I wrote a script that repeatedly queries [this Reddit API endpoint](https://www.reddit.com/reddits.json) until all the subreddits are stored in an array, `all_subs`:

```
all_subs = []
for sub in <repeated request here>:
    all_subs.append({"name": display_name, "subscribers": subscriber_count})
```

The script has been running for close to ten hours, and it's about halfway done (it gets rate-limited every three or four requests). When it's finished, I expect an array like this:

```
[
    { "name": "AskReddit", "subscribers", 16751677 },
    { "name": "news", "subscribers", 13860169 },
    { "name": "politics", "subscribers", 3350326 },
    ... # plus one million more entries
]
```

**Approximately how much space in memory will this list take up?**

Comment: That is not an array, that is a *list*.

Comment: Which version of Python? CPython (the "standard" implementation from python.org)? Version 2 or 3?

Comment: Also, 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fixed it :-) And its 64-bit version 2 of Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This depends on your Python version and your system, but I will give you a hand figuring out about how much memory it will take. First thing is first, [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) only returns the memory use of the *object* representing the container, not all the elements in the container.

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is
>   accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.
>
> If given, default will be returned if the object does not provide
>   means to retrieve the size. Otherwise a TypeError will be raised.
>
> `getsizeof()` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an
>   additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the
>   garbage collector.
>
> See [recursive sizeof recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) for an example of using `getsizeof()`
>   recursively to find the size of containers and all their contents.

So, I've loaded up that recipe in an interactive interpreter session:

So, a CPython *list* is actually a heterogenous, resizable arraylist. The underlying array only contains pointers to Py_Objects. So, a pointer takes up a machine word worth of memory. On a 64-bit system, this is 64 bits, so 8 bytes. So, *just for the container* a list of size 1,000,000 will take up roughly 8 million bytes, or 8 megabytes. Building a list with 1000000 entries bears that out:

```
In [6]: for i in range(1000000):
   ...:     x.append([])
   ...:

In [7]: import sys

In [8]: sys.getsizeof(x)
Out[8]: 8697464
```

The extra memory is accounted for by the overhead of a python object, and the extra space that a the underlying array leaves at the end to allow for efficient `.append` operations.

Now, a dictionary is rather heavy-weight in Python. Just the container:

```
In [10]: sys.getsizeof({})
Out[10]: 288
```

So a *lower bound* on the size of 1 million dicts is: 288000000 bytes. So, a rough lower bound:

```
In [12]: 1000000*288 + 1000000*8
Out[12]: 296000000

In [13]: 296000000 * 1e-9 # gigabytes
Out[13]: 0.29600000000000004
```

So you can expect about about 0.3 gigabytes worth of memory. Using the recipie and a more realistic `dict`:

```
In [16]: x = []
    ...: for i in range(1000000):
    ...:     x.append(dict(name="my name is what", subscribers=23456644))
    ...:

In [17]: total_size(x)
Out[17]: 296697669

In [18]:
```

So, about 0.3 gigs. Now, that's not a lot on a modern system. But if you wanted to save space, you should use a `tuple` or even better, a `namedtuple`:

```
In [24]: from collections import namedtuple

In [25]: Record = namedtuple('Record', "name subscribers")

In [26]: x = []
    ...: for i in range(1000000):
    ...:     x.append(Record(name="my name is what", subscribers=23456644))
    ...:

In [27]: total_size(x)
Out[27]: 72697556
```

Or, in gigabytes:

```
In [29]: total_size(x)*1e-9
Out[29]: 0.07269755600000001
```

`namedtuple` works just like a `tuple`, but you can access the fields with *names*:

```
In [30]: r = x[0]

In [31]: r.name
Out[31]: 'my name is what'

In [32]: r.subscribers
Out[32]: 23456644
```