# Why does sys.getsizeof() report the same size for two instances even though one has an extra attribute?

Tags: python

```
import sys

class MyObject:
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

obj1 = MyObject("Tushar", 50)
obj2 = MyObject("Tushar", 50)
obj2.age = 20

print(sys.getsizeof(obj1))  # 56
print(sys.getsizeof(obj2))  # 56
```

Why is `obj2` only 56 bytes when it has an extra `age` attribute?

Comment: What were you hoping `sys.getsizeof()` would give you?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python/3373511 (read through several of the answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof()` only gives you the system memory use for the direct reference. Instance objects don't store attributes *directly*, by default those are stored in a dictionary object referenced by the `__dict__` name. And dictionaries store keys and values as references too, `sys.getsizeof()` would only give you the memory size of the dictionary internal C arrays and other internal bookkeeping attributes, not the keys or values themselves.

From the [`sys.getsizeof()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

You'd have to *recursively* collect object sizes until you run out of attributes or key-value pairs, etc. The documentation links to [this example code](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) to show you how to do this.

That specific recipe has no support for instances but here passing in the `__dict__` attribute of your objects should suffice:

```
>>> total_size(obj1.__dict__)
303
>>> total_size(obj2.__dict__)
383
```

so the two objects have different total size attribute dictionaries.

Note that there are many places where Python *caches or interns objects*, so don't take these memory sizes as absolutes. For example, [small integers are interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), so there is only ever a single `50` integer object in CPython memory, but it was counted separately in the above `total_size()` output.

And modern CPython versions can also save memory by having the `__dict__` dictionary objects of those two instances [share data on the keys](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/), in the assumption that the vast majority of instances of a given class will have the same attributes.

Take this into account when analysing `sys.getsizeof()` data. If you wanted to profile Python memory use, you'd be much better of learning how to use the [`tracemalloc` tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#module-tracemalloc) first.

Comment: @TusharJajodia well, you didn’t say anything about what you were trying to do, so I covered the spectrum.