# Python pympler.asizeof.asizeof returning 0 for generator-expression

Tags: python, sys, generator-expression

I'm currently comparing generator-expressions and list-comprehensions for my final project and in the course of this wanted to compare their memory footprint. (Heads up: I read this post but couldn't answer the question I'll present to you [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python) )
I started by defining two arbitrary instances for each type of structure:

```
a = [i for i in range(10)]
b = (i for i in range(10))
```

Now I first tried to analyze their length with `sys.getsizeof` which yields 192 for `a` and 88 for `b` (and 48 for the blank `range(10)`).

I wasn't 100% certain that `sys.getsizeof` included the `range`-instance because that may just be referenced by the generator expression-instance and afaik references aren't counted with `getsizeof`, so I also tried calling `pympler.asizeof.asizeof` for both instances, which yields 504 for `a`, 48 for the pure `range(10)` and strangely 0 for `b`.
Resorting to the pympler docs I noticed that there was an `ignored` argument to `asizeof` which ignored certain types. I tried it again with `ignored=False` but got the exact same results.

What I wanted to know is why it is that the generator-expressions is of size 0 to `asizeof` and if I can rely on `sys.getsizeof` to give me the correct value for the generator(it seems realistic after all).