# Memory usage of a Python program on Quadtree

Tags: python, memory, quadtree

i have implemented a Quadtree in Python(spyder) .I want to know the total memory usage by the structure when i insert objects into it. 
Read a lot of answers on related questions, but they doesnt seem to work or hve their own problems.
Issues- Because of a number of functions and due to (may be) the garbage collector , psutil doesnt give any satisfactory results. Memory profiler takes a long time for large dataset and dont know how much effective it will be. As i read somewhere , objects also take extra memory because they reference some other objects.

Comment: can you please add you code here ?

Comment: What you want is the `size` module that has a recursive `sizeof`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python