# How to know shape of image collection object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-image

I am reading all images of a folder from following code

```
from skimage.io import imread_collection
img_dir = 'cats/*.jpg'
col = imread_collection(img_dir)
```

for getting shape or size of col i used following:

```
col.shape
```

but get `AttributeError: 'ImageCollection' object has no attribute 'shape'`

how to solve this problem

Comment: try len instead of shape.  try col[0].shape  , directory can't have shape, image do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageCollection` is a list of images, so you have to access individual images with their index.

From the [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.ImageCollection):

```
>>> coll = io.ImageCollection(data_dir + '/chess*.png')
>>> len(coll)
2
>>> coll[0].shape
(200, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

try len instead of shape. try col[0].shape , directory list can't have shape, image do. so iterate in list and get all shapes of many images.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer above, you could use `len(col)` to determine the length of the collection, i.e. how many images are there in the collection.

But I think the question title is a bit misleading, one might think what you are trying to achieve is to get the size (i.e. in Bytes) of an object, in this case, you could use `sys.getsizeof(col)` and this will return the size of this object, in Bytes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450034/7613480)

P.S. this answer should be posted as a comment, but I couldn't do so not having enough rep, apologies to the SO community.

---

Edit: 
If you are interested in getting the size in Bytes of an object, please go through the other answers posted under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449560/7613480), as the `sys.getsizeof()` isn't always accurate.