# Is there a way to examine how much memory an image is occupying with python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

pillow provides `size` to examine the resolution of an image.

```
>> from PIL import Image
>> img = Image.open('Lenna.png')
>> img.size
(512, 512)
```

is there a way to examine how many memory the image is occupying? is the image using 512*512*4 Bytes memory?

Comment: by **memory** do you mean, it's size in a permanent storage medium (hdd, ssd etc) or in a Dynamic Memory (RAM)

Comment: thank for your reminder.  RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sys` library to get the size of an object in bytes. The difference with Kai's answer is that he's calculating the size of the image on the disk, while this calculates the size of the loaded python object (with all its metadata):

```
import sys

sys.getsizeof(img)
```

EDIT: After seeing this [website](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609), `sys.getsizeof()` seems to work mainly for primitive types.

You could have a look at a more thorough implementation (`deep_getsizeof()`)  [here](https://github.com/the-gigi/deep/blob/master/deeper.py#L80) .

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python) gives also a lot of details.

And finally, there is also the `pympler` library that provides tools to calculate the RAM memory used by an object.

```
from pympler import asizeof

asizeof.asizeof(img)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. is this very close to the RAM that the image is occupying actually?

Comment: Actually, after reading this website, this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609 , it seems to work mostly for primitive types. See my edits

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
print os.stat('somefile.ext').st_size
```

or

```
import os
os.path.getsize('path_to_file.jpg')`
```