# Get actual size of protocol buffer object

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying to calculate the exact size of the protocol buffer objects.

I went through the following links: [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python) and https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/

But the protocol buffer objects do not include **dict** in dir(object) since it can cause corruption by people trying to manually add parameters to it. This is based on my understanding, though it might not be complete or correct.

So, I started with this protocol buffer message definition

```
syntax = "proto2";

package test;

message Inner {
  optional bytes inner_id = 1;
  optional string inner_name = 2;
  optional int64 inner_value = 3;
}

message Outer {
  optional bytes uuid = 1;
  optional string name = 2;
  enum Test {
    kOne = 1;
    kTwo = 2;
  }
  optional Test testing = 3;
  repeated Inner inner_list = 4;
}
```

This is sample usage

```
import uuid
from test_pb2 import Inner, Outer

x = Outer()
x.uuid = uuid.uuid4().bytes
x.name = "test"
x.testing = Outer.kOne
x.inner_list.add(inner_id=uuid.uuid4().bytes, inner_name="ok1", inner_value=1)
x.inner_list.add(inner_id=uuid.uuid4().bytes, inner_name="ok2", inner_value=2)
x.inner_list.add(inner_id=uuid.uuid4().bytes, inner_name="ok3", inner_value=3)

print id(x.inner_list)
print id(x.inner_list[0].inner_id)
print id(x.inner_list[1].inner_id)
print id(x.inner_list[2].inner_id)
print id(x.inner_list[0].inner_name)
print id(x.inner_list[1].inner_name)
print id(x.inner_list[2].inner_name)
print id(x.inner_list[0].inner_value)
print id(x.inner_list[1].inner_value)
print id(x.inner_list[2].inner_value)
```

The id of inner_id, inner_name and inner_value is the same even though they belong to a different list and have different values.

So, the modification of code in above link did not work as expected

```
def get_size(obj, seen=None):
    """Recursively finds size of objects"""
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    # Important mark as seen *before* entering recursion to gracefully handle
    # self-referential objects
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum([get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()])
        size += sum([get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()])
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in obj])
    else:
        try:
            for desc, _ in obj.ListFields():
                if desc.label == FieldDescriptor.LABEL_REPEATED:
                    size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in getattr(obj, desc.name)])
                else:
                    size += get_size(getattr(x, desc.name), seen)
        except Exception as ex:
            pass
    return size
```

Since it tripped at the id check (obj_id in seen) and did not account for the different memory requirement between "ok1" and "ok2" for example

Could anyone please explain the reason between the same "ids" and how to correctly calculate the size of protocol buffers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AaronHall can you please check this and help me find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simpler than you expected. `Outer` is a `Message`, and all messages have a [`ByteSize` function](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message.ByteSize).

```py
from google.protobuf.message import Message

message: Message = Outer()
size_in_bytes = message.ByteSize()
print(f"Message is {size_in_bytes} bytes.")
```

If you add type hints and use an IDE, it should suggest a few useful functions on `message`.

Comment: I don't know if this answers the question. For unpopulated messages it returns just `0`. Probably this is not what the op wants. As far as I understand, the sum of the sizes of the datatypes of the individual fields is searched.

Comment: An empty message has a serialized size of 0 bytes. The function is working correctly.