# Actual size of an integer object in python

Tags: python, python-internals

Why does the following produce such different results?

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int) # same as sys.getsizeof(object), sys.getsizeof(type)
400

>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
```

Is the actual size of the item `1` equal to the size of the object (400) + the size of the actual integer value (28) = 428, or how exactly does the integer/object creation work here?

Comment: Python **is not** C. `sys.getsizeof(int)` returns the size of the object referenced by `int`, which in this case, is the class-object for the built-in type `int`. That is not the same as the size of any of its instances. Note, integer objects *can have different sizes*. So compare `sys.getsizeof(0), sys.getsizeof(1), sys.getsizeof(10000000000)`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/10366273)

Comment: `int` is of type `<class 'type'>` and so are your other examples which is why they are all the same size and `1` is of type `<class 'int'>` which is why it's sized 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These objects aren't the same type which is why they aren't the same size:

```py
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(type)
416
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>

>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
```

There is a good answer on the general sizes of most objects and how they scale [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/10366273).

And for the record, `<class 'type'>` is a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) and there is a super long answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949) on what those are and why.