# Why masked arrays seems to be smaller compared to unmasked array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size, mask

I am trying to understand what's the size difference between a numpy masked array and a normal array with nans.

```
import numpy as np
g = np.random.random((5000,5000))
indx = np.random.randint(0,4999,(500,2))
mask =  np.full((5000,5000),False,dtype=bool)
mask[indx] = True
g_mask = np.ma.array(g,mask=mask)
```

I used the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/2132157) to compute the size of the object:

```
import sys
from types import ModuleType, FunctionType
from gc import get_referents
​
# Custom objects know their class.
# Function objects seem to know way too much, including modules.
# Exclude modules as well.
BLACKLIST = type, ModuleType, FunctionType
​
​
def getsize(obj):
    """sum size of object & members."""
    if isinstance(obj, BLACKLIST):
        raise TypeError('getsize() does not take argument of type: '+ str(type(obj)))
    seen_ids = set()
    size = 0
    objects = [obj]
    while objects:
        need_referents = []
        for obj in objects:
            if not isinstance(obj, BLACKLIST) and id(obj) not in seen_ids:
                seen_ids.add(id(obj))
                size += sys.getsizeof(obj)
                need_referents.append(obj)
        objects = get_referents(*need_referents)
    return size
```

That gives me the following result:

```
getsize(g)
>>>200000112
getsize(g_mask)
>>>25000924
```

Why the unmasked array is bigger compared to the masked array? How can I estimate the real size of the masked array vs the unmasked array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [23]: g = np.random.random((5000,5000)) 
    ...: indx = np.random.randint(0,4999,(500,2)) 
    ...: mask =  np.full((5000,5000),False,dtype=bool) 
    ...: mask[indx] = True 
    ...: g_mask = np.ma.array(g,mask=mask)
```

Comparing the `g` array with the `_data` attribute of `g_mask`, we see that the latter is just a `view` of the former:

```
In [24]: g.__array_interface__                                                  
Out[24]: 
{'data': (139821997776912, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5000, 5000),
 'version': 3}
In [25]: g_mask._data.__array_interface__                                       
Out[25]: 
{'data': (139821997776912, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5000, 5000),
 'version': 3}
```

They have the same data buffer, but their `id` is different:

```
In [26]: id(g)                                                                  
Out[26]: 139822758212672
In [27]: id(g_mask._data)                                                       
Out[27]: 139822386925440
```

Same for the mask:

```
In [28]: mask.__array_interface__                                               
Out[28]: 
{'data': (139822298669072, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '|b1')],
 'typestr': '|b1',
 'shape': (5000, 5000),
 'version': 3}
In [29]: g_mask._mask.__array_interface__                                       
Out[29]: 
{'data': (139822298669072, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '|b1')],
 'typestr': '|b1',
 'shape': (5000, 5000),
 'version': 3}
```

Actually with this construction, the `_mask` is the same array:

```
In [30]: id(mask)                                                               
Out[30]: 139822385963056
In [31]: id(g_mask._mask)                                                       
Out[31]: 139822385963056
```

`__array_interface__` of the masked array is that of the `._data` attribute:

```
In [32]: g_mask.__array_interface__                                             
Out[32]: 
{'data': (139821997776912, False),
```

`nbytes` is the size of the data buffer for an array:

```
In [34]: g_mask.data.nbytes                                                     
Out[34]: 200000000
In [35]: g_mask.mask.nbytes                                                     
Out[35]: 25000000
```

A boolean array has 1 byte per element, and a float64, 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks any idea on how I can estimate the size correctly?

Comment: What's missing in my description?  `nbytes`?  Masking adds the size of the `mask`.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how can I get the size in bytes of the two different objects. What I am trying to understand if the masked array consume a lot more memory compared to the unmasked array.

Comment: I tried to explain.  The masked array is actually 2 arrays - sum the size of the two.  Do you understand how numpy arrays are stored?  And the difference between a `copy` and `view`?

Comment: Yes I know what a view is,  I simply did not know that with data.nbytes you could have the bytes. g_mask.mask.nbytes is exactly the number of values of the bytes of the mask I was wondering if there was also some other bytes used by the mask class.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.ndarray` has no [`tp_traverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_traverse), so it's incompatible with the `getsize` function you're trying to use. The GC system can't see the references owned by the `ndarray` part of your masked array. Particularly, the `base` of `g_mask` is not getting included in your output.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how can I get the size of the two objects for a comparison?