# what is the equivalent of ls() function of r in python?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

Basically what ls() does in r is that it is used to list the names of all the objects that are present in the working directory. I want to do the same in python, could someone please help me with this ? I'm a python newbie ;-;

Comment: `ls()` lists the objects in its current *environment*. Unless specified otherwise this is your "workspace". It does *not* list the *working directory*, for which you use `dir()`. Do you want a Python equivalent for the former or latter method (the latter being `dir()` in Python AFAIK).

Comment: I'd like a python code for the former please

Comment: That should be `dir()` or some object-specific approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686644/python-find-current-objects-in-memory#62686771

Answer (score 1):

you can use `os.listdir()`

```py
import os

print(os.listdir('.')) # here '.' for current directory.
```