# How to iterate over all variables in memory in Python, for debugging purposes?

Tags: python

While debugging I want to know if, at some point, I am holding an instance of a particular class. I want to iterate over all the variables that I currently have any reference to, filter them with `isinstance`, and then, if I find an instance of that class, then I will decide if it's good practice or not to use it there.

It's basically just a quick and dirty way to explore my options and discover things about code I'm only getting into.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_objects?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that works! I was just thinking that that's the king of thing that the garbage collector would know how to do!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, got a problem though: it doesn't tell me *where* it found that object, i.e. what name currently holds it. Any way to know that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62686644/3001761

Comment: This question didn't really help, I think using `gc` is a better lead. Actually, we're getting somewhere with `gc.get_referrers()`.

Comment: However, I'm looking for a name to get to that reference, get_referrers only gets me instance of objects, not their names.

Comment: I think there's a solution in there somewhere, I'm just to tired to see it right now. Will be back on it tomorrow :)