# How to calculate the size of Django model object?

Tags: python, django

I explored and found `sys.getsizeof()` to get the size of an object, but it is giving the same size for below objects:

```
import sys
>>> obj = MyModel.objects.first()
>>> sys.getsizeof(obj)
64
>>> obj.description = 'abcdefghi....xyz'  # entered a very long string here
>>> sys.getsizeof(obj)
64
```

No matter which model objects I use, the size is always 64, even if the object contains too many fields.

What am I doing wrong, and how to get the actual size of an object in bytes?

Edit: Some of you are suggesting this question [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python), but it says to use `sys.getsizeof()` function, which is giving me unexpected result. PS. I am new to django and python

Comment: I saw the getsizeof() function there only, but the results are not as expected

Comment: **`getsizeof()`** return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, ***but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation-specific***. Which means, the value of `sys.getsizeof(django_model_instance)` need not be true.

Comment: So, is there any existing function that may help?

Comment: Not specific to Django but maybe profilers can help? (https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler)