# Size of different data types in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been using Pycharm for Python executions.
I'm using version 3.8.
I'm not able to get the exact size of the data types in Python.
I refereed the following link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-size-of-an-object-in-python/
But when I executed the same examples as mentioned in the link I didn't get a similar output.

```
import sys 
a = sys.getsizeof(12) 
print(a)
b=sys.getsizeof('geeks') 
print(b)
```

I executed the above code.
The output for a was 14 and for b was 30.
But according to the link, it should have been 28 and 54 respectively.

Please Help if there's any other way of calculating the size for the datatypes.

Comment: Different python version, different size. The linked article is bad: nothing about the version used, and also the table is wrong. it seems the author just checked with few example, without understanding how Python work (e.g. characters are coded 1,2 or 4 bytes per char, depending of the required size for larger character). Int: they are "bigint", so size could grow. bad article. I would expect some more research.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes you are right different Python version have different size. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

***The size of each datatype in Python 3.8 is as follows:***

Size of int is: 12

Size of float is: 16

Size of str is: 25

Size of list is: 20

Size of tuple is: 12

Size of dict is: 120

Size of set is: 100

Size of frozenset is: 100

Size of None is: 8

Size of Ellipsis is: 8

Size of Object is: 8

Size of Lambda is: 60

Size of Function-ref is: 60

Size of Exception is: 32

***Got this by using the Script:***

def f(): return

types = [int(0), float(0), str(), list(), tuple(), dict(), set(), frozenset(),
None, ..., object(), lambda: None, f, Exception()]

names = ["int", "float", "str", "list", "tuple", "dict", "set", "frozenset",
"None", "Ellipsis", "Object", "Lambda", "Function-ref", "Exception"]

sizes = list(map(lambda x: x.**sizeof**(), types))

for t, s in zip(names, sizes):
print("Size of {} is: {}".format(t, s))

Comment: No. Size of `int` is not the size of `int(0)`. You should be more precise. As the accepted answer: int size is variable, and it depends on the value.