# Memory footprint of big Python dictionaries after all keys are removed

Tags: python, dictionary, memory

Recently I did a simple test in Python, wondering what is the memory impact of huge dictionaries (~ 10 million keys) and how to empty them efficiently (not all keys at once). I use the `clear()` method as reference, and I'm looking for the amount of memory still in use after all keys have been removed.

In my tests, the `clear()` method is very good at deleting and giving back the memory to the os; whereas when I use `del` or `pop` the memory consumed after all keys are removed it's still quite large. To measure the memory used by an object I use a function `get_size` found online, present at the beginning of my source code (also available [here](https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/)).

How can the `clear` method be so efficient compared to `pop`or `del` ?

Code of my tests can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Willena/cf5a4484b4b0253a001ee3bd8398459f) as well as the tests result.

Comment: The `clear()` method knows that it's removing everything, so it can reclaim all the memory. Deleting individual elements in the middle of a dictionary doesn't allow the rest of the memory to be reclaimed unless it rehashes the dictionary.

Comment: As addition, you can force a resize by replacing the dictionary with a copy.

Comment: @scenox yep, that's how I usually do it. In the rare cases where I've built a giant dictionary where I have to wittle it down, then I will do all the `del d[key]` for efficiencies sake but then one final `d = dict(d.items())` although `d.copy()` might be sufficient

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the workaround :)

Comment: You should cite and link to the original author of the recursive `get_size()`, whoever they are. Is it Wissam Jarjoui from 2016 [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38515297/202229]?

Comment: When you say *"how to empty them efficiently (not all keys at once)"*, what does that mean (memory-efficient? shorter downtime for locking dictionary?) That you assume it's more efficient to empty them piecemeal? Or that you functionally require that you can't clear the entire dictionary at once? I don't think those assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid excessive hash table rebuilds, `pop` and `del` don't resize a dict's underlying hash table. Removing entries one by one will never shrink a dict's hash table.

Resizing only happens if a dict runs out of room on insertion (which *can* shrink the dict, due to how dummy entries work in the implementation), or if unrelated technical details force a rebuild (like having to un-split a split-table dict).

`clear` will throw away the old hash table entirely, though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! This answer plus other comment on the question itself helped me :)