# Why is the size not changing in the below python code?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, size

I am learned about getsizeof() operator, and cannot
understand why:

import sys

A=[(1,2,3,4)]

B=[()]

print(sys.getsizeof(A))

print(sys.getsizeof(B))

both print 64 . This is size in bytes but why isn't it changing?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.getsizeof()` The size that actually goes up in memory.

so, empty string (like "" ) occupies 49bytes.

```
print(sys.getsizeof(''))
print(sys.getsizeof(en))


# result
# 49
# 76
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! because you are passing both tuple. if want to check the size you need to pass the A values as list and B value as tuple. like this
`

```
import sys 
A=[1,2,3,4] 
B=[()]

print(sys.getsizeof(A)) 
88
print(sys.getsizeof(B))
64
```

`
here is some more examples:

```
import sys
a =[1, 2]
b =[1, 2, 3, 4]
c =[1, 2, 3, 4]
d =[2, 3, 1, 4, 66, 54, 45, 89]
print(sys.getsizeof(a))
print(sys.getsizeof(b))
print(sys.getsizeof(c))
print(sys.getsizeof(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just a minimal size of list object.

```
import sys

A=(1,2,3,4)
A_LIST=[(1,2,3,4)]
B=[()]
B_2=[(),()]

print(sys.getsizeof(A))
print(sys.getsizeof(A_LIST))
print(sys.getsizeof(B))
print(sys.getsizeof(B_2))

#72
#64
#64
#72
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python) you can find out more about sizes