# Python Memory Mystery with pd.DataFrames, np.ndarrays, and multiprocessing's Queue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory, multiprocessing

### Introduction

Hello Fellow Internauts!

I am encountering a strange error when working with three popular Python libraries: pandas, NumPy, and multiprocessing. Whenever I put a pandas DataFrame (containing NumPy arrays) into a multiprocessing queue, the memory of the data frame is altered. This is visible by checking the memory of the data frame before putting it and after retrieving it from the queue.

### System and Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04
- python==3.8.5
- numpy==1.21.4
- pandas==1.3.4

### Bug Replication

Here is the Python interpreter session that showcases the issue:

First, I imported the involved libraries:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
```

Then, I created a basic array and a pandas DataFrame holding 3 arrays. The memory usage thus far makes sense.

```py
>>> array = np.ones([720, 1280, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'frames': [array, array, array]})
>>> array.nbytes
2764800
>>> df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
8294960
```

Where things become unclear to me is how after placing and retrieving the pandas DataFrame into the queue. The memory is reduced significantly! Where does it go?!

```py
>>> queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=5)
>>> queue.put(df)
>>> new_df = queue.get()
>>> new_df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
560
```

### Initial Attempts

Does it affect np.ndarrays as well? (Nope)

```py
>>> queue.put(array)
>>> new_array = queue.get()
>>> new_array.nbytes
2764800
```

Perhaps, I should copy the DataFrame before putting into the queue? (Nope)

```py
>>> queue.put(df.copy())
>>> new_df = queue.get()
>>> new_df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
560
```

Is this present in other Queue implementations? (Nope)

```py
>>> from queue import Queue
>>> new_queue = Queue(maxsize=5)
>>> new_queue.put(df)
>>> new_df = new_queue.get()
>>> new_df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
8294960
```

### Conclusion

As much as I want to just avoid this issue by using `queue.Queue`, I am developing a multiprocessing program that won't work with `queue.Queue`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am sorry if this is a silly mistake that is noted in the multiprocessing documentation.

### EDIT #1 (03/13/2022 at 1:35 pm CST):

After further testing, I determined that this issue is caused by NumPy arrays. Here is an example:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> array = np.ones([720, 1280, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> array_dict = {'frames': [array, array, array]}
>>> array.nbytes
2764800
>>> queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=5)
>>> queue.put(array_dict)
>>> new_array_dict = queue.get()
>>> sys.getsizeof(array_dict['frames'][0])
2764944
>>> sys.getsizeof(new_array_dict['frames'][0])
144
>>> array_dict['frames'][0].nbytes
2764800
>>> new_array_dict['frames'][0].nbytes
2764800
```

Not sure how to fix this issue, but the `pd.DataFrame` memory usage report is incorrect because `sys.getsizeof` is obtaining the wrong memory usage of the NumPy arrays. I will continue debugging until the culprit is found!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in this [SO forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python), I noticed that the issue was the pickling (which is done by the `multiprocessing.Queue` internally) of NumPy arrays and the `sys.getsizeof` function. Here is an example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pickle
>>> import sys
>>> with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as f:                                                                                                                                                                      
...     pickle.dump(a, f)                                                                                                                                                                                  
...                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> with open('test.pkl', 'rb') as f:                                                                                                                                                                      
...     new_a = pickle.load(f)                                                                                                                                                                             
...                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
22118544
>>> sys.getsizeof(new_a)
144
```

[One solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228005/13231446), not perfect but sufficient, comes from the linked SO forum. It uses `pickle.dump` to measure the memory usage. It works for the initial use-case as well.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import multiprocessing as mp                                                                                                                                              
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'frames': [a,a,a]})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> q = mp.Queue(maxsize=5)                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> q.put(df)                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> new_df = q.get()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> len(pickle.dumps(new_df))                                                                                                                                                                              
22119157                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> len(pickle.dumps(df))                                                                                                                                                                                  
22119157
```

If anyone has a better solution, I would gradly appreciate it and accept it. Thank you!