# Get the (C) size of a (C) type in a Python extension

Tags: python, setup.py, python-extensions

I'm writing a C extension for Python and need to pass the size of a C type to the compilation. So I'll want to do

```py
extra_compile_args = ['-DSIZEOF_MYTYPE=32']
```

in my `setup.py`.  My question is: how can I get the size? (32 here)

If my target were pure C and I use autoconf, then I could use `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF`, if writing a Ruby extension there is `check_sizeof` in the [mkmf module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html), is there some similar facility (presumably, like autoconf and Ruby's mkmf, by making a test-compile which calls C's `sizeof` and prints the result to stdout, and capturing that) in Python?  Or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: Afraid not: tt's the size of a C type that I need.

Comment: [`struct.calcsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize) or [`ctypes.sizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof) would probably be the most appropriate built-in tools for the job, but they can't parse your C headers to read your type definitions or anything like that, so you'd have to repeat the type definitions in a format `struct` or `ctypes` understands.

Comment: That `sizeof` works just fine -- many thanks!  If you would like to convert that comment to an answer, I'll make as solved