# Determining the byte size of a scipy.sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is it possible to determine the byte size of a scipy.sparse matrix? In NumPy you can determine the size of an array by doing the following:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.zeros((100, 100, 100).nbytes)
8000000
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A sparse matrix is constructed from regular numpy arrays, so you can get the byte count for any of these just as you would a regular array.

If you just want the number of bytes of the array elements:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> a = csr_matrix(np.arange(12).reshape((4,3)))
>>> a.data.nbytes
88
```

If you want the byte counts of all arrays required to build the sparse matrix, then I think you want:

```
>>> print a.data.nbytes + a.indptr.nbytes + a.indices.nbytes
152
```

Comment: Nice, that worked very well. I'm more interested in the first case, but the second case is interesting. Does that memory size represent the entire object?

Comment: No, just the arrays. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python.

Comment: For coo_matrix, it should be a.col.nbytes + a.row.nbytes + a.data.nbytes

Comment: Isn't there a generic way that works for all types of sparse matrices? Thanks!

Comment: Best solution I found so far is through pickles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228005/1822138

Comment: to make sure it works for different types of sparse matrices: `sum([sys.getsizeof(i) for i in sparse_matrix.data])`