# How to get the size of a python object in memory?

Tags: python, memory

I would like to know that how much memory an object occupies in python.

I am talking of use defined objects not the built in data structure and array in python.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python