# Size of third-party object in memory

Tags: python, biopython

The `sys.getsizeof()` function returns the size of an object in memory, in bytes. As this function may return inaccurate results for third-party [objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450034/580010), how do I determine how much memory a BioPython object is using?

I loaded a 286MB file using [example](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) code (modified):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
handle = open("example.gb", "rU")
records = list(SeqIO.parse(handle, "genbank"))
handle.close()
```

and `sys.getsizeof(records)` indicates that it is using 268KB.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.getsizeof(obj)` returns the size of the object `obj` itself, not the size of any other object it might reference one way or another:

```
>>> l = []
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
72
>>> zero = 0
>>> sys.getsizeof(zero)
24
>>> l.append(zero)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
104
>>> 72 + 24
96
>>> l.append(zero)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
104
>>> l.append(zero)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
104
>>> l.append(zero)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
104
>>> l.append(zero)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
136
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, bar=None):
...         self.bar = bar
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> sys.getsizeof(f)
64
>>> f.bar = 1
>>> sys.getsizeof(f)
64
>>> f.bar = l
>>> sys.getsizeof(f)
64
>>>
```

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't answer the question

Comment: How do I determine the amount of memory a BioPython object is using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python might be a good starting point