# Why does sys.getsizeof() return a value that is 33 bytes more than the actual size?

Tags: python-3.x, byte, sizeof

The following code returns 35 as the answer:

```
print(sys.getsizeof((1024).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')))
```

Shouldn't the int.to_bytes() return a byte representation of 1024 that is 2 bytes long because the documentation mentions:

```
The integer is represented using length bytes. An OverflowError is raised if the integer is not representable with the given number of bytes.
```

What am I understanding incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you neglected to account for the garbage collector overhead that comes with each python object on creation. Additionally take note that `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't count the sizes of the objects that an object refers to.

Comment: Is there any way to get just the object size without any of the overhead?

Comment: There is no easy way. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python for more info