# Python sys.getsizeof() gives size 1056 for every Class and gives 56 for every object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, oop

I had an interview yesterday for Python Developer role. The interviewer asked

1. What is **size** of **class** and **object** in Python?
2. **Where are they stored?**

For the second question "**Where are they stored?**", I answered "**In RAM**" (Correct me if I am wrong!)

Now, coming to the first question "What is **size** of **class** and **object** in Python?", I did Google search and came across `sys.getsizeof()` function.

I ran small test using different classes and their objects. But it was always printing **"1056" for classes** & **"56" for objects** .

So, I added inheritance to one of the class and add some more properties & methods to other class. But the result was same.

**This might be because they are just storing pointers to respective RAM locations.**
**But then what can be the possible answer for the question interviewer asked me?**

Experiment Code:

```
import sys
class Car:
  def __init__(self,carName):
    self.carName = carName

  def getCarName(self):
    return self.carName

class EVCar(Car):
  def __init__(self,carName,chargingCapacity):
    super().__init__(carName)
    self.chargingCapacity = chargingCapacity

  def getCharging(self):
    return self.chargingCapacity
  
  def getMileage(self):
    return self.chargingCapacity//100
  
class Mobile():
  def __init__(self,name,os,battery,price) -> None:
      self.name = name
      self.os = os
      self.battery = battery
      self.price = price

  def getAllDetails(self):
    return "Mobile Name : {} | OS : {} | Battery : {} | Price : {}".format(self.name, self.os, self.battery, self.price)
  def getMobileName(self):
    return "Mobile Name : {}".format(self.name)
  def getMobileOS(self):
    return "Mobile OS : {}".format(self.os)

  def getMobileBattery(self):
    return "Mobile Battery : {}".format(self.battery)
  def getMobilePrice(self):
    return "Mobile Price : {}".format(self.price)


c = Car('Tata Motors')
print(c.__class__)

print("Class memory :",sys.getsizeof(Car))
print("Object Size using sys.getsizeof() :",sys.getsizeof(c))
print("Object size using __sizeof__() :",c.__sizeof__())
print("--------------------------------------------------------------\n")

e = EVCar('Nexon',120)
print(e.__class__)

print("Class memory :",sys.getsizeof(EVCar))
print("Object Size using sys.getsizeof() :",sys.getsizeof(e))
print("Object size using __sizeof__() :",e.__sizeof__())
print("--------------------------------------------------------------\n")

m = Mobile('Google Pixel', 'Android 12', "5000mAH", "50000/-")
print(m.__class__)
print("Class memory :",sys.getsizeof(Mobile))
print("Object Size using sys.getsizeof() :",sys.getsizeof(m))
print("Object size using __sizeof__() :",m.__sizeof__())


#  https://www.google.com/search?q=python+class+occupies+1056+bytes&oq=python+class+occupies+1056+bytes
#  https://pymotw.com/3/sys/limits.html (Search for: 1056 on the page)
#  https://realpython.com/storing-images-in-python/ (Search for: 1056 on the page)
```

**Output**:

```
<class '__main__.Car'>
Class memory : 1056
Object Size using sys.getsizeof() : 56
Object size using __sizeof__() : 32
--------------------------------------------------------------

<class '__main__.EVCar'>
Class memory : 1056
Object Size using sys.getsizeof() : 56
Object size using __sizeof__() : 32
--------------------------------------------------------------

<class '__main__.Mobile'>
Class memory : 1056
Object Size using sys.getsizeof() : 56
Object size using __sizeof__() : 32
```

Comment: Read more than one answer from these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33978/17457042, https://stackoverflow.com/q/449560/17457042

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python maybe this helps you about this topic br