Memory size of python tuple and array
I want to explain the memory footprint of Python tuple and array.
Here is the code I'm using (Python 3.12.3):
import sys
import array

a = (1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
b = array.array('d', (1.1, 2.2, 3.3))

print(sys.getsizeof(a))
print(sys.getsizeof(b))
print(sys.getsizeof(a[0]))
# Output
# 64
# 104
# 24

The output doesn't meet my expectations. I thought that Python float object consists of 3 fields: 1 value field and two metadata field (reference count and pointer to the object type). Each of these fields takes 8 bytes so every float takes 24 bytes (which agrees with sys.getsizeof(a[0])). Since Python tuple stores either the objects themselves or pointers to them and float is a primitive, I would expect the memory size of tuple to be len(a) * 24 which for my case is 72. My output prints 64 bytes. Where to find the missing 8 bytes?
Additionally, I expected the array data type to occupy less space because it should (?) hold only raw float values for each element (value field) and metadata fields are common for the whole array. But this is not the case and array occupies more space than the tuple. Why?

I don't think sys.getsizeof works recursively. That's why the size of a seems small, but I can't tell the specific size breakdown.

Try the example code from the link in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865746/1862861, for a memory usage function that works recursively.

Tuples are rather more compact than other container objects, due to their immutability.  They have the standard object header, a length field, and pointers to each element (note: NOT the elements themselves!) - and absolutely nothing else.  Arrays are more complicated, due to the possibility of their size changing: I'm pretty sure that they consist of two blocks of memory (like a list), a fixed-size base object, containing a pointer to a separate block that contains the actual data (which allows that block to be moved in case of a size change, without invalidating the ID of the base object).
